# Java recursion program not sorting the array

Tags: java, recursion, bubble-sort

```
public class bubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] arr = {50,40,30,20,10};
        bubbleSort1(arr,0,arr.length-1);
        display(arr);
    }

    public static void bubbleSort1(int[] arr,int i, int li) {
        if (i==0) {
            return;
        }
        if (i==li) {
            bubbleSort1(arr,0,li-1);
            return;
        }
        if (arr[i]>arr(i+1)) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
        bubbleSort1(arr,i+1,li);
    }

    public static void display(int[] arr) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing bubble sort and the code doesn't work, but I dont't know why it  only prints the array which I am providing to it.

Comment: You are calling the method with the value `0` for `i` and the first line in that method is `if(i==0) {  return;  }`. So is it really a surprise that your method does absolutely nothing?

Answer (score 2):

First line of your method `bubbleSort1(...)` is `return;` when `i == 0`. You're `main` method calls the method with: `bubbleSort1(arr,0,arr.length-1);` ... i == 0 - so your method isn't sorting anything.

It should look more like:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] list = { 50,40,30,20,10 };
        bubbleSort1(list,list.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
    public static void bubbleSort1(int[] list, int listLength) {
        if (listLength==1) { return; }
        for (int i=0; i<listLength-1; i++) {
            if(list[i] > list[i+1]) {
                int temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = temp;
            }
            bubbleSort1(list, listLength-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```java
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

I've taken the liberty to rename variables for clarity and removed the display method as `Arrays.toString(list)` method provides this functionality for free :)